# Mono Socket Server drops clients when it does big operations

Tags: c#, sockets, mono

Mono 3.99
My socket server runs fine in Windows, but on Linux/Mono it drops a socket.
Whenever the server runs an operation longer than a fraction of a second, the socket is disconnected, but occasionally the client stays connected. The client is Silverlight 4 and is run from Windows.

More reproducible is when two clients connect. The first connects fine. The second connects, but when the server runs an operation, my server disconnects the first client. When this happens, the first client sends exactly 0 bytes.

I have my clients in a static list so they won't be GC'd, and timeout is set high. The only thing I can think of is the client might be pinging the server, and in that window of time when it handles the message, it's not in a receive state. But that would make sockets extremely fragile.

Is there any reason - Mono-related or otherwise - that could cause this behavior?

```
  static void OnBeginAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient _MessageClient = _MessageListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            byte[] _ReceiveBuffer = new byte[8197];
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_MessageClient.GetStream());
            ClientDefinition newClient = new ClientDefinition();
            newClient.Socket = _MessageClient.Client;
            newClient.Socket.ReceiveTimeout = 7000; newClient.Socket.SendTimeout = 7000;
            newClient.username = "undefined" + clients.Count;
            newClient.receiveBuffer = new byte[8197];
            clients.Add(newClient);

            newClient.Socket.BeginReceive(newClient.receiveBuffer, 0, 8196, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveComplete), newClient);
            _MessageListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(OnBeginAccept), null);
            Console.WriteLine("new client accepted");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { LogError(ex); }
    }


  static void OnReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ClientDefinition fromClient = null; //Wrapper for Socket
        fromClient = (ClientDefinition)ar.AsyncState;
        if (fromClient == null) return;

        try
        {
            if (!fromClient.Socket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fromclient (" + fromClient.username + ") not connected");
                CloseClient(fromClient);
                return;
            }
            int receiveLength = 0;
            receiveLength = fromClient.Socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (receiveLength == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Receivelength == 0");
                CloseClient(fromClient);
            }


            SocketMessage message = null;
            message = Serializer.Deserialize<SocketMessage>(fromClient.receiveBuffer);
            System.Array.Clear(fromClient.receiveBuffer, 0, receiveLength);

            /******Here is where I handle the messages. And when doing an operation that is 'big', a client is closed.*****/

            fromClient.Socket.BeginReceive(fromClient.receiveBuffer, 0, 8196, SocketFlags.None, new                         AsyncCallback(OnReceiveComplete), fromClient);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in OnReceiveComplete: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + "obj: " + ex.Source);
            CloseClient(fromClient);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was I had a strong reference to the **Socket**, not the **TcpClient**, and when the program accumulated enough garbage it disposed the NetworkStream, which consequently closed the underlying socket. This behavior was not identical to .NET. Solved by storing the accepted TcpClient in a static list.